# Silverlight 4, WCF with net.tcp endpoint, proxy not requesting clientaccesspolicy.xml

Tags: wcf, silverlight-4.0, net.tcp

I've been trying to have my Silverlight application work with a WCF net.tcp binding the whole day and couldn't make it, even though it seems to me I've done everything right, including after some googling...

I had a WCF service with a basicHttpBinding endpoint which worked perfectly, and as my WCF service and my Silverlight application are on the same network, told myself "why not trying something else than HTTP ?"

---

So I began googling to see what had to be done, and here's the list of what I did :

### Server

- Checked that Net.Tcp Listener Adapter service was running

### IIS

- Enabled net.tcp binding on my website, with binding information set to "4502:*"
- Added net.tcp protocol to the Application that hosts my WCF service
- Added a policy in the clientaccesspolicy.xml file to allow socket connection on ports 4502-4536

### WCF Service

- Added a net.tcp binding with Security set to None
- Added an endpoint with this binding for my service, keeping the regular HTTP one

---

After doing all this, I can use my WCF service with WcfTestClient, it sees the two endpoints (HTPP and net.tcp), and both of them work like a charm.

In my Silverlight application, I can update my service reference (which I added with the HTTP address of my service, not the TCP one), and it also sees the two endpoints because it added the TCP endpoint in the ServiceReferences.ClientConfig. As I saw when googling, netTcpBinding is not supported in Silverlight, thus it describes the binding as a custom binding with a  and a  element.

I saw on the different tutorials I followed that, as for the HTTP binding, Silverlight asks for a socket policy file to check if the client has access to the WCF service. In SL4 Beta, this file was requested by TCP on port 943. As of SL4 RC and RTM, it's requested by HTTP on port 80, as it is for the HTTP bindings.

The thing is, when I launch my application with the proxy set to use the net.tcp binding, I checked with Fiddler, the clientaccesspolicy.xml is **NOT** requested at any time, and I get the *classic* error when the socket policy file is not present :  TCP error code 10013: An attempt was made to access a socket in a way forbidden by its access permissions.

After googling, I found out that SL looks for this file with the IP address of the server, not its name, but trying http://IP_OF_MY_SERVER/clientaccesspolicy.xml in a browser on my client machine serves the file as expected...

So I'm a bit lost here, I would really like to have it working to see something else than HTTP with WCF...

Someone has any bit of a clue to guess what happens ???
As the service works as expected with WcfTestCLient with the net.tcp binding, I'm guessing this has something to do specifically with SL...

Thanks for reading :-)

Comment: Here some one has done ...  http://www.silverlightshow.net/items/WCF-NET.TCP-Protocol-in-Silverlight-4.aspx

Comment: Thanks, this is one of the tutorials I had a look at yesterday... I did all the things explained in this tutorial but still no luck